# Intermittent PHP warning: "imap_open(): Couldn't open stream"

Tags: php, gmail-imap

I have a cron job that pulls emails from a gmail account once every 5 minutes.  I am using the [ddboer/imap](https://github.com/ddeboer/imap) library to authentication and every so often (approx once every 2 - 3 days) it has an issue connecting.

My code is fairly basic and looks something like this:

```
$server = new Server('imap.gmail.com');

try {
    $connection = $server->authenticate($username, $password);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The output when it fails is:

```
[E_WARNING] Authentication failed for user "user@example.com": imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/validate-cert}
imap_alerts (0):
imap_errors (1):
- Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (authenticate)
```

It has been very difficult to troubleshoot since the issue is intermittent.  The following common issues have already been addressed:

- [Less Secure Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879) have been enabled/allowed
- [Display Unlock Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/displayunlockcaptcha) has been completed
- Credentials, port and endpoint are all correct
- My server's network is not experiencing connectivity issues during times when it fails to connect

The important thing to note here is that the script succeeds +99% of the time and only fails occasionally, but it happens regularly enough that it prompted this question.

Comment: Providing code is great, but your code isn't relevant here. As you say, it works "+99% of the time" and I assume it isn't changing between attempts. But without code, the question comes down to, "why can I occasionally not connect to this remote server that I don't have any control over?" Which is not something that anyone here can answer definitively. It could be connectivity problems, it could be rate limiting, it could be any number of things. So, write a retry mechanism into your code and call it a day.

Comment: @miken32 - Thanks for explaining and I mostly agree with you, but there's this *"...which is not something that anyone here can answer definitively"*.  With something like 10 million users here, I am rolling the dice on the possibility that one of them is intimately familiar with gmail's authentication mechanism and **could** possibly provide a definitive answer based on what I'm doing.

Comment: @miken32 - also please note, the reason you gave is primarily why I've held off asking this question in the past but at this point it's been going on regularly for over ***3 years***. Would be really great to get some insight into why.

Comment: Also note that a vote to close is not saying it's a bad question, that's what downvotes are for. It's just not something that someone can point to a specific thing and say "that's your problem." Hopefully my answer will at least help to make it something manageable.

Comment: @miken32 - I understand, no offense taken and thanks for your candor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that:

- your code almost always works
- you're connecting to a server that you have no control over
- this server may be thousands of kilometres away, with dozens of networks between you

I'd just accept that sometimes $#i† happens, and make sure you're prepared for it:

```
$server = new Server('imap.gmail.com');

$retries = -1;
while (true) {
    try {
        $connection = $server->authenticate($username, $password);
        break;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($retries++ > 2) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            break;
        }
        sleep(pow(2, $retries));
    }
}
```

So in case of an error, this would retry after 1 second, then retry after 2 seconds, then retry after 4 seconds, before giving up. Tweak these thresholds as needed.

Comment: Sorry for accepting this a billion years late - I have since migrated this app the the gmail api and surprisingly I've found it even less reliable than imap!